# What is an unbiased estimate of population R-square?

Tags: estimation, multiple-regression, r-squared, bias

I am interested in getting an unbiased estimate of $R^2$ in a multiple linear regression.

On reflection, I can think of two different values that an unbiased estimate of $R^2$ might be trying to match.

1. **Out of sample $R^2$:** the r-square that would be obtained if the regression equation obtained from the sample (i.e., $\hat{\beta}$) were applied to an infinite amount of data external to the sample but from the same data generating process.
2. **Population $R^2$:** The r-square that would be obtained if an infinite sample were obtained and the model fitted to that infinite sample (i.e., $\beta$) or alternatively just the R-square implied by the known data generating process.

I understand that [adjusted $R^2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Adjusted_R2) is designed to compensate for the overfitting observed in sample $R^2$. Nonetheless, it's not clear whether adjusted $R^2$ is actually an unbiased estimate of $R^2$, and if it is an unbiased estimate, which of the above two definitions of $R^2$ it is aiming to estimate.

Thus, my questions:

- What is an unbiased estimate of what I call above out of sample $R^2$?
- What is an unbiased estimate of what I call above population $R^2$?
- Are there any references that provide simulation or other proof of the unbiasedness?

Comment: The question what formula for adj. R^2 is less biased has been raised e.g. [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/25214/3277).

Comment: Thanks. I'm now reading the reference you mention: Yin, P., & Fan, X. (2001). Estimating $R^2$ shrinkage in multiple regression: A comparison of different analytical methods. The Journal of Experimental Education, 69(2), 203-224.

Answer (score 16):

### Evaluation of analytic adjustments to R-square

@ttnphns referred me to the Yin and Fan (2001) article that compares different analytic methods of estimating $R^2$. As per my question they discriminate between two types of estimators.
They use the following terminology:

- $\rho^2$: Estimator of the squared population multiple correlation coefficient
- $\rho_c^2$: Estimator of the squared population cross-validity coefficient

Their results are summarised in the abstract:

> The authors conducted a Monte Carlo experiment to investigate the
>   effectiveness of the  analytical formulas for estimating $R^2$ shrinkage,
>   with 4 fully crossed factors (squared  population multiple correlation
>   coefficient, number of predictors, sample size, and  degree of
>   multicollinearity) and 500 replications in each cell. The results
>   indicated  that the most widely used Wherry formula (in both SAS and
>   SPSS) is probably not  the most effective analytical formula for
>   estimating $\rho^2$. Instead, the Pratt formula  and the Browne formula
>   outperformed other analytical formulas in estimating $\rho^2$ and $\rho_c^2$,
>   respectively.

Thus, the article implies that the Pratt formula (p.209) is a good choice for estimating $\rho^2$:

$$\hat{R}^2=1 - \frac{(N-3)(1 - R^2)}{(N-p-1)} \left[ 1 + \frac{2(1-R^2)}{N-p-2.3} \right]$$

where N is the sample size, and p is the number of predictors.

### Empirical estimates of adjustments to R-square

Kromrey and Hines (1995) review empirical estimates of $R^2$ (e.g., cross-validation approaches). They show that such algorithms are inappropriate for estimating $\rho^2$. This makes sense given that such algorithms seem to be designed to estimate $\rho_c^2$. However, after reading this, I still wasn't sure whether some form of appropriately corrected empirical estimate might still perform better than analytic estimates in estimating $\rho^2$.

#### References

- Kromrey, J. D., & Hines, C. V. (1995). Use of empirical estimates of shrinkage in multiple regression: a caution. Educational and Psychological Measurement, 55(6), 901-925.
- Yin, P., & Fan, X. (2001). Estimating $R^2$ shrinkage in multiple regression: A comparison of different analytical methods. The Journal of Experimental Education, 69(2), 203-224. [PDF](http://www.statpt.com/applied_gen/yin_2001.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

We made some progress regarding this. Thus here an updated answer.

**Assumptions**

All existing comparisons for this  (thus also the results summarized by Jeromy, and all claims I make dependent on all regression assumptions being met, and the predictors being multivariate normally distributed. For a more formal treatment, see [Shieh (2007)](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1094428106292901) or [Karch (2020)](https://online.ucpress.edu/collabra/article/6/1/45/114458/Improving-on-Adjusted-R-Squared)

**1. Population $R^2$**

As Jeremey notes, this is commonly called squared population multiple correlation coefficient $\rho^2$.  It is defined as the amount of variance explained by the true regression model. The unbiased estimator has been derived theoretically in [Olkin & Pratt (1958)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-29/issue-1/Unbiased-Estimation-of-Certain-Correlation-Coefficients/10.1214/aoms/1177706717.full) and is correspondingly known as Olkin-Pratt estimator. Until recently, this estimator was not available in any software as it's nontrivial to compute it. However, I showed how to do that [(Karch, 2020)](https://online.ucpress.edu/collabra/article/6/1/45/114458/Improving-on-Adjusted-R-Squared) and provide an [R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/altR2/index.html) for extracting it from a fitted regression model.

Note that unbiasedness might not be what you want. Especially Bayesians tend to get angry at the Olkin-Pratt estimator as it can return negative values, which of course has a posterior probability $0$. At the same time, sometine returning negative values is needed for unbiasdness. If you consider other optimality criteria, most notably, lowest MSE, the results change dramatically, see [Karch (2020)](https://online.ucpress.edu/collabra/article/6/1/45/114458/Improving-on-Adjusted-R-Squared),  [Which is better: r-squared or adjusted r-squared?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353807/which-is-better-r-squared-or-adjusted-r-squared/451772#451772), and [Would the real adjusted R-squared formula please step forward?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/508268/would-the-real-adjusted-r-squared-formula-please-step-forward/508363#508363).

**2. Out of sample $R^2$**

First a warning: The squared population cross-validity coefficient $\rho_c^2$ is not equivalent to the description in the question

> the r-square that would be obtained if the regression equation obtained from the sample (i.e., $\hat{\beta}$) were applied to an infinite amount of data external to the sample but from the same data generating process.

If we call the value described in the quote $\rho_c(\hat{\beta})$, $\rho_c^2$ is actually the expectation $E[\rho_c(\hat{\beta})]$ [(Shieh,2007)](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1094428106292901). After consulting the latest paper on the issue [(Shieh, 2007)](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1094428106292901), it seems that no unbiased estimator for this exists yet.