# Distinguishing between different notions of $R^2$

Tags: regression, cross-validation, r-squared, intuition

What is the distinction between

- $R^2_{pop}$  – the population R-squared
- $R^2_{out}$  – the out-of-sample R-squared
- $R^2_{c.v.}$   – the squared population cross-validity coefficient **?**

These objects have been mentioned in earlier posts [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55929/what-is-an-unbiased-estimate-of-population-r-square), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25214/how-to-choose-between-the-different-adjusted-r-squared-formulas?lq=1) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63389/does-adjusted-r-square-seek-to-estimate-fixed-score-or-random-score-population-r/63766#63766).

I would appreciate an intuitive explanation. Ideally, some counter-examples would illustrate when the differences between these objects matter, and what goes wrong if one is used in place of another.