# Definition of the adjusted $R^2$ coefficient

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, references, r-squared

In the context of ordinary least square regression with observed responses $Y$ and residual errors $\hat \varepsilon$, the $R^2$ coefficient is defined as 
$
  R^2 = 1-\frac{\|\hat \varepsilon\|^2}{\|Y - \bar Y\|^2}. $
This is non-decreasing in the addition of covariates to the model, and hence the *adjusted* $R^2$ coefficient defined by $
R^2_a = 1-\frac{\|\hat \varepsilon\|^2/(n-1)}{\|Y - \bar Y\|^2/(n-p-1)}
$
is often prefered.

Why is *this particular* adjustment of $R^2$ the most commonly used? What is the underlying justification?

---

*Notes*

- I'm mostly interested in historical and rigorous references. I haven't found a satisfactory answer on wikipedia or in the regression books I consulted.
- I'm not looking for the one explanation to end all explanations; my goal is to get a good grasp on different understandings of $R^2_a$.

Comment: This answer seems related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/63097/176202

Comment: [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/63100/1352) and [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/55932/1352) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The explained variance will have (n-p-1) degrees of freedom, while the total variance will have n-1 degrees of freedom. So, you normalize the sums of squares with these quantities. Look at multiple regression output description [here](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/anovareg.htm). This is closely related to the F-test statistics reported for multiple regression.

Comment: This is self-evident from the definition. Here I'm really asking about the fundamental _why_ of why this adjustment is used instead of any other. Isn't there something more profound?